# 10 - 230 V DC voltage detector using STM32

Tags: voltage-measurement, capacitor-charging

I am working on a stud welder device capable of weld M3 ~ M8 bolts and the principle is to charge the caps in the range of 10 - 230 V DC, So we have a 220 to 160 V AC step down transformer and after rectification we will have around maximum 230 V DC on the output of the rectifier. I will use a STM32 uC for this project and want to make a voltage detection circuit for which, whenever the caps voltage in the range of 10 - 230 V DC the STM32 will allow the switch (there will be a tactile switch on the welder gun) to trigger the welding cycle.
Here is the question: what type of circuit or IC will perform this for me?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your STM32 feature built in ADC? Otherwise just a comparator set to 10 V. But won’t it be a lousy welder if you set it for 180 V but the switch triggers on 10 V only non the less?

Comment: Yes, that’s how you do it as long as they share ground. Please draw a schematic.

Comment: @winny Of course it has, My assumption is to place a voltage divider in ADC input and convert 10~230Vdc to 0~3.3V for ADC and I will have full control over welding Cycle. But is it safe for Microcontroller?

Comment: 0-3.3V is safe for the microcontroller.   watch out for ground bounce.

Comment: @Jasen you are right about ground bouncing, if it makes problem I have to think about isolating the grounds, I think 

Comment: I think grounding the microcontroller close to the internal  groubnd of the welding circuit will probably be enough,  but you might need isolation on some otther I/o